# Lazy service injector PHPDoc

Tags: php, phpstorm, silex, phpdoc, pimple

I am looking for a solution to declare properly a lazy service injector for the PhpStorm IDE. Here is an example:

```
$app = new Silex\Application();

/**
* ???
*/
$app['file'] = function() {
  return new M_file();
};
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't declare the type of each array element independently. One solution is assign the value to a new variable where you want to use it (in a controller class for example) and declare the type of that variable.

Comment: Check Silex/Pimple related plugins, they may help. In general, [Advanced Metadata](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html) is usually used for such stuff, but I don't think it work well with arrays (but does work with `$app->get('someService')` kind of stuff; Look at what IDE helper for Laravel generates, see https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper).

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for this plugin I didn't know it. Very useful indeed! Unfortunately that doesn't solve this issue...